# Moving Domain.wordpress.com to a new domain

Tags: domain, hosting

I have created my website at the following address.

http://musivision.wordpress.com/

I would like to move my website to the following domain:

http://musivision.ca

I found a link on domain mapping 'http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-existing-domain/

however, it seems to be forcing me to use WordPress hosting which I don't want to do. I want to stay with my current hosting company.

In short I would like to:

1) Keep the website that I created
2) Remove the Wordpress from my domain and transfer to 'http://musivision.ca' 
3) Keep the same hosting that I use.

Answer (score 2):

If I am correctly understanding your setup, you are using wordpress hosting now, but want to make your domain be a self-hosted copy of your blog

1) Export all your current blog entries/layouts/etc.
2) Change new domain not to forward to the existing blog.
3) Set up wordpress on your new domain
4) Import all your blog entries/layouts/etc.
5) optionally, delete wordpress hosting once all is done.

Here's a blog post that will give you some examples of plugins that will backup/restore your blog, which is what you need to do to export/import:
http://www.carefulcash.com/the-3-best-backup-solutions-for-a-wordpress-blog/
Though, certainly you could do your own research and find others that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your own hosting in tandem with a wordpress.com blog since the main difference with wordpress.org is that it offers it's own hosting.

If you want to use your personal domain name you can either map it to the blog or you can port your blog to your own hosting using the Wordpress publishing platform downloadable from http://wordpress.org/download/

Also remember that wordpress.com doesn't allow you to include advertisements of any kind, so it could be a good idea to move to your own hosting if you want to monetize your blog.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my interpretation of your question into the mix. It sounds like you may be referring to your *DNS Hosting*, not your *website hosting*, is that correct? Or, maybe you're saying that you don't want to move your *domain registration*?

If the former, as far as I know, to have your custom domain hosted at wordpress.com, you ***need*** to use their DNS hosting (anyone, please correct me if I'm wrong here).

If the latter, you don't need to move your domain registration -- you can keep your domain registration at, e.g. GoDaddy, and set your *nameservers* to:

```
NS1.WORDPRESS.COM
NS2.WORDPRESS.COM
NS3.WORDPRESS.COM
```

The link you provided has links to instructions for common registrars at the bottom.